# EXC_BAD_ACCESS during using std::vector in Swift

Tags: c++, swift, swiftui, vector, exc-bad-access

I am trying to use std::vector in Swift code according to what is written in Swift documentation (https://www.swift.org/documentation/cxx-interop/) and Apple tutorial (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10172/) but I have EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

I am using Xcode 15.1 to crate app for iOS. My app has only main view, that have only one button:

```
 Button(action: {
        var vect = getVectorObject.getVector()
    }, 
    label:{
        Text("Button")
    })
```

header file that contains declaration of object:

```
@interface getVectorObject : NSObject
+ (std::vector<int>)getVector;
@end
```

and Objective C++ file with definition:

```
@implementation getVectorObject

+ (std::vector<int>)getVector {
    std::vector<int> vec = {1,2,3};
    return vec;
}
@end
```

When I compile the project everything is OK but when I run simulation and I press the button I have an error: EXC_BAD_ACCESS in "getVectorObject.getVector()"

As I understand from the Swift documentation and Apple tutorial, something like this should be possible to do.

I tried to use "var" and "let" but I have the same error. I read the documentation and StackOverflow but I cannot see any solution.